# Traveling to the US on a B1/B2 visa as a dual citizen

Tags: usa, passports, b1-b2-visas, dual-nationality

I'm a dual citizen of countries A and B. Citizens of both A and B require a visa to travel to the US. I hold a B1/B2 visa in my A passport and visit the US often for both business and pleasure. My A passport is about to expire soon, while B passport will be valid for a few more years. I'm curious if:

- There's a simplified process of obtaining a B1/B2 visa as a citizen of B, given that I already have that visa as a citizen of A. Ideally that process won't require me to resubmit all documents and pay the full visa fee.
- It's possible to get admitted into the US with a valid B passport and expired A passport that includes the visa.

Thanks!

Comment: The latter. There are many duplicate questions about this; your visa is still valid even though it is in an outdated passport, just bring it.

Comment: @Aganju The new passport must be from the same country as the old one with the visa.

Comment: @Aganju I couldn't find any duplicate questions specifically about traveling with two passports of different countries when one is expired and has a valid visa and the other is still valid but can't be used to enter the country without a visa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no "simplified process" to obtain a new visa with your other nationality. It's the same process you went through before and requires the same full visa fee to be paid.

You can either do that, or you can renew your passport for your original nationality, for which you already hold the US visa. You then show both passports (from the same country) when entering the US.

Comment: I was in the same situation as @Egor and what I can say is that the Visa approval for my second passport, and I strongly suspect that was because I already had the prior approval.